# Display proper html content in react. Content is Dynamic from Database

Tags: reactjs

I am building blogging application. and i use summernote for write a blog content.
Blog content are stored in database like this :

```
<b>hi</b>.....<b>share if you like</b>
```

But when i fetch and try to disply blog content it will display same html code
ex:

`<b>hi</b>.....<b>share if you like</b>` insted of **hi** ..... **share if you like**.

Now how to display blog content with all styles?

**Snap of table:**
[image]

**Snap of html output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render html content.

```html
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "<p>your html content</p>"}}></div>
```

Comment: @DhruvRaval Can you please check it now. I have missed one `{}`

Comment: @DhruvRaval My bad! Didn't noticed the edit notification while editing.